# Unable to connect to phpMyAdmin via SSh tunnel on Bitnami LAMP stack

Tags: ssh, phpmyadmin, putty, bitnami

I've tried searching for a solution to my problem both here and elsewhere online but I've come up empty, so I'm hoping someone can help. I must initially point out this issue has shown that this area is a complete blind spot for me, so I'm sorry if I'm missing something blatantly obvious, or I'm not explaining thoroughly enough.

I'm trying to access phpMyAdmin on a Bitnami LAMP stack via SSH tunnel, as per guide here: https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/phpmyadmin/. I seem to be able to establish the SSH tunnel, and everything looks correct in the PuTTY event log in terms of opening connection for forwarding, etc, but when I try to navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin in a browser as stated in the guide, I am returned the error 'This site can’t be reached. 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.' After I receive this error I check the PuTTY event log and it shows 'forwarded port closed'. Is anyone able to provide me with some troubleshooting steps I can go through or possible solutions for what the problem may be please? Again, if I've not provided enough information please ask and I'll do my best to update what I can.

For background, I am the nearest thing to an IT lead for a GP and this LAMP stack is used for an online system accessed by both patients and staff for a specific health condition. It was independently created by a GP who has since left the practice, but before doing so he imparted onto me what we thought to be enough information/instruction to keep the system "ticking over" until we found a developer to produce a new one (I'm struggling to get in touch with said GP, so currently asking for their help isn't an option). It is a Bitnami LAMP stack created in Microsoft Azure, and has recently developed a SMTP authentication error whenever a patient/staff member needs to request a new or reset an existing password. I am attempting to access phpMyAdmin to check/reconfigure the SMTP server settings in the hopes of rectifying the situation. I do have some systems experience, previously working as a System Analyst/Technician for a hospital, but as I previously stated this area (servers, etc.) are a bit of a blind spot.

Many thanks to anyone willing and able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

It seems that the SSH tunnel was not properly created and that's why you can't access phpMyAdmin now. You can try to reconfigure the port forwarding configuration again or you can edit the Apache's configuration to allow remote requests from your IP to the phpMyAdmin application. To do so:

- Edit the /opt/bitnami/conf/bitnami/phpmyadmin.conf file and substitute the `Require local` line with `Require ip YOUR_PUBLIC_IP`.

> If you do not know your public IP, you can access http://myip.bitnami.com to get that information

- Restart Apache and access phpMyAdmin using http://MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS/phpmyadmin